# universal 0-dimensional separable metric subspaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\ \mathscr U:=(U\ \delta)\ $ be a separable metric space which is universal for all finite metric spaces, i.e. for every finite metric space $ \mathscr X:=(X\ d)\ $ there
exists an isometric embedding of $\ \mathscr X\ $ into
$\ \mathscr U.$

**Q:**   Does there exist a 0-dimensional subset
$\ C\subseteq U\ $ in $\ \mathscr U\ $ such that space
$\ (C\,\ \delta|C\!\times\!C)\ $ is universal for all finite metric spaces?

Similar questions hold for

- the subcategory of the above metric spaces of diameter
    $\le 1;$
- the subcategory of the above metric spaces which are complete.

> *As long as I know, these questions are **open**.*

PS. **Mathematicians**, please, be tolerant! Do not edit my **STYLE**.

=====================================================

**their story**

```
    she talked talked talked
    then married
    his confidence
    his cocksure ways

    she kept talk-talk-talking
    for the next twenty years
    till she broke down
    that damn confidence of his
    that cocky style

    these days
    she plays mean darts
    drinks beer
    talk-talk-talks to poor bastards for miles
    searching for the brimming confidence
    for the cocksure smile
```

*Włodzimierz Holsztyński
-- 1998-02-12*

Comment: Not editing your style—well, I think it's clear how the community feels on that, but it's also clear that you don't intend to change; but why is there a poem?

Comment: @LSpice, I've promoted my style of mathematical editing over long years on the Internet, on several groups, there were hundreds upon hundreds of participants. Until StackExchange, there was never any issue about it, people took it in stride. At StackExchange, some people act (edit, downvote, etc) against my style. A friend recited a proverb for me (he told me that it was from a holy book): ***give a man power, and he will make angels cry*.**